# Register a new type of user in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5.5

### I encounter an error in my register page of user in laravel 5.5 like below:

****SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tb_users_user_name_key"\n
DETAIL:  Key (user_name)=(user_deo) already exists. (SQL: insert into "tb_users" ("name", "user_name", "phone", "email", "password", "default_password", "updated_at", "created_at") values (doe, user_deo, 017244668, sample@gmail.com, $2y$10$96qs6iC6HVbBZ2rtfNcsg.DiBjA14g/k9DQPzFWqXSh153sZCuUPy, 123456, 2018-06-18 01:47:36, 2018-06-18 01:47:36) returning "user_id")****

**with validation fields of user like this:**

> Validator::make($data, [
>               'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
>               'user_name' => 'required|string|unique:tb_users,user_name',
>               'phone' => 'required|string|unique:tb_users,phone',
>  
>               'email' => 'required|string|email|unique:tb_users,email',
>               'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
>           ]);

**I just want to know why Validation unique column in Laravel, is not work. It should pass error messages from Validation to register form back.**

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because you already have the user_name of "user_deo" in your database? Thus getting a unique violation.

Comment: I just want to know why Validation unique column in Laravel, is not work. It should pass error messages from Validation to register form back.